# Javascript store array of highest length in temp array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, switch-statement

I have two arrays that when generated can be either equal or one longer than the other.

I need to get the longest array if they are not equal and use the length to control a loop.

```
$.ajax({

    url: "/static/Data/q_learning.json",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {

        var data2 = data;
        // console.log(data);
        $.ajax({

            url: "/static/Data/sarsa.json",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (data1) {
                var data1 = data1;
                var json_data = data2;
                var json_data1 = data1;

                json_data = json_data[Object.keys(data2)[0]];
                json_data1 = json_data1[Object.keys(data1)[0]];
                var result = [];
                var biggest = [];

                switch (json_data) {
                    case json_data.length > json_data1.length:
                        biggest = json_data;
                        break;
                    case json_data.length < json_data1.length:
                        biggest = json_data1;
                        break;
                    case json_data1.length > json_data.length:
                        biggest = json_data1;
                        break;
                    case json_data1.length < json_data.length:
                        biggest = json_data;
                        break;
                    default:
                        biggest = json_data1;
                }



                console.log(biggest);
                for (var i in biggest)
                    result.push([i, json_data[i], json_data1[i]]);

                console.log(result);
```

I am switching on one of the arrays and checking if it is smaller or larger in length. Then assigning the larger array length to a temp array biggest.

If they are equal I don't think it matters which array is assigned as they are both the same length.

Sometimes it works but the problem I'm having is the biggest length array is not always being assigned to the biggest temp array.
[image: graph]

The above graph is showing the two data as the same timline but one is larger that the other.

The below image is the graph when I set one particular varibale higher that the other. But when i set the other variable to be higher they are equal as the other image shows.
[image: Grahp 2]
It's probably staring me in the face but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: switch is the WRONG thing to use here. Switch should be for checking a fixed value.

Comment: What are `data1` and `data2`? Can you provide example data please?

Comment: I tried if and else if statments with the same result.

Comment: Your checks are also basically duplicates.

Comment: data1 and data 2 are from ajax calls to json files. I'll put up the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. 
I was getting the size of an array on a json object.

The below code solved it.

```
                json_data = json_data[Object.keys(data1)[0]];
                json_data1 = json_data1[Object.keys(data2)[0]];
                var json_data_size = Object.keys(json_data).length;
                var json_data1_size = Object.keys(json_data1).length;
                var result = [];
                var biggest = [];

                if(json_data_size>json_data1_size){
                    biggest = json_data;
                }else if(json_data_size<json_data1_size){
                    biggest = json_data1;
                }else if(json_data_size==json_data1_size){
                    biggest = json_data1;
                }


                console.log(biggest);
                for (var i in biggest)
                    result.push([i, json_data[i], json_data1[i]]);

                console.log(result);
```